# UWP - How to check NumLock and CapsLock status?

Tags: c#, keyboard, uwp, capslock, num-lock

How can check for CapsLock or NumLock status and see if they are enabled or disabled (on or off)? As far as I searched, I know only it's possible to check if they are pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it on your Page using:

```
var keystate = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.NumberKeyLock);
var isNumLocked = (keystate & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Locked) != 0;
```